# Workbooks.OpenText Error "Expected function or variable"

Tags: excel, vba

Why does my code below not work? It highlights the `.OpenText` part and states:

> Expected function or variable

```
Dim Indata As Excel.Workbook

Set Indata = Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:="C:\Users\thePunter\Desktop\Count_Types_062016.txt", DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to set the workbook variable while using the OpenText method but OpenText doesn't return a workbook reference.  Do this instead

```
Dim Indata As Excel.Workbook
 Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:="C:\Users\thePunter\Desktop\Count_Types_062016.txt", DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True)
Set Indata = ActiveWorkBook
```

Comment: I hate that this is the answer. It should just return a workbook.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it -odd enough though-

```
'...
Dim Indata As Excel.Workbook
Call Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:="C:\Users\thePunter\Desktop\Count_Types_062016.txt", DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True)
Set Indata = ActiveWorkbook
Indata.Close False
'...
```

However, while working with csv and txt files, I find highly effective the [EOF command.](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html)

Comment: Thank you, All.  I will give them all a try.

Comment: Please, check the green mark once an answer has fulfilled your answer and most importantly, **try them**, most of the users here won't be able to help if you "suddenly" (a week, a month after) change your original requirements or ask for new ones.